# ComboBox with both filter and auto-complete

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, autocomplete

Has anyone succeeded with WPF's ComboBox auto-complete and filter functionalities? I have spent several hours now and haven't been able to nailed it. This is WPF + MVVM Light. Here is my setup.

**VM layer**

A ViewModel that provides the following properties:

- `FilterText`(`string`): Text that user has typed in TextBox area for filtering. Fires change notification on `FilteredItems`.
- `Items`(`List<string>`): This is the main data source containing all options.
- `FilteredItems`: Filtered list of `Items` using `FilterText`.
- `SelectedOption` (`string`): Currently selected option.

**View layer**

A ComboBox where user can choose from the drop-down options only. However, user should be allowed to type text in the textbox area and the dropdown should filter out items that do not begin with typed text. First matching item should automatically be appended to the textbox (auto-complete that is). Here are my bindings:

- `ItemsSource`: binds to `FilteredItems`, One-way
- `Text` binds to `FilterText`, Two-way
- `SelectedItem` binds to `SelectedOption`, Two-way

`IsTextSearchEnabled` is set to true for enabling auto-complete.

Problem with this setup is that as soon as user types the first letter, auto-complete is triggered and tries to locate the first matching entry and if found, sets `SelectedItem` to that entry, which in set the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` to that item, which in turn triggers filter operation and the dropdown is left with only one entry that fully matches `Text`, which is not what it should be like.

For example, if user types "C", auto-complete will try to locate first entry starting with "C". Let's say that the first matching entry is "Customer". Auto-complete will select that entry, which will set `SelectedItem` to "Customer" and therefore `Text` will also become "Customer. This will invoke `FilterText` because of binding, which will update `FilteredItems`, which will now return only one entry, instead of returning all entries starting with "C".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your approach is too complicated.
You can implement a simple Attached Behavior to achieve a filtered suggestion list while autocomplete is enabled.

This example doesn't require any additional properties except the common source collection for the `ComboBox.ItemsSource`. The filtering is done by using the `ICollectionView.Filter` property. This will modify only the view of the internal source collection of the `ItemsControl`, but not the underlying binding source collection itself. Setting `IsTextSearchEnabled` to `True` is not required to enable autocomplete.

The basic idea is to trigger the filtering rather on `TextBox.TextChanged` than on `ComboBox.SelectedItemChanged` (or `ComboBox.SelectedItem` in general).

**ComboBox.cs**

```
class ComboBox : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsFilterOnAutoCompleteEnabled attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabledProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled",
      typeof(bool),
      typeof(ComboBox),
      new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), ComboBox.OnIsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabledChanged));

  public static void SetIsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) =>
    attachingElement.SetValue(ComboBox.IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement) =>
    (bool)attachingElement.GetValue(ComboBox.IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabledProperty);

  #endregion

  // Use hash tables for faster lookup
  private static Dictionary<TextBox, System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox> TextBoxComboBoxMap { get; }
  private static Dictionary<TextBox, int> TextBoxSelectionStartMap { get; }
  private static Dictionary<System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox, TextBox> ComboBoxTextBoxMap { get; }
  private static bool IsNavigationKeyPressed { get; set; }

  static ComboBox()
  {
    ComboBox.TextBoxComboBoxMap = new Dictionary<TextBox, System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox>();
    ComboBox.TextBoxSelectionStartMap = new Dictionary<TextBox, int>();
    ComboBox.ComboBoxTextBoxMap = new Dictionary<System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox, TextBox>();
  }

  private static void OnIsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabledChanged(
    DependencyObject attachingElement,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox
      && comboBox.IsEditable))
    {
      return;
    }

    if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
    {
      ComboBox.DisableAutocompleteFilter(comboBox);
      return;
    }

    if (!comboBox.IsLoaded)
    {
      comboBox.Loaded += ComboBox.EnableAutocompleteFilterOnComboBoxLoaded;
      return;
    }
    ComboBox.EnableAutocompleteFilter(comboBox);
  }

  private static async void FilterOnTextInput(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
      () =>
      {
        if (ComboBox.IsNavigationKeyPressed)
        {
          return;
        }

        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        int textBoxSelectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
        ComboBox.TextBoxSelectionStartMap[textBox] = textBoxSelectionStart;

        string changedTextOnAutocomplete = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBoxSelectionStart);
        if (ComboBox.TextBoxComboBoxMap.TryGetValue(
          textBox,
          out System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox))
        {
          comboBox.Items.Filter = item => item.ToString().StartsWith(
            changedTextOnAutocomplete,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
      },
      DispatcherPriority.Background);
  }

  private static async void HandleKeyDownWhileFiltering(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    var comboBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
    if (!ComboBox.ComboBoxTextBoxMap.TryGetValue(comboBox, out TextBox textBox))
    {
      return;
    }

    switch (e.Key)
    {
      case Key.Down 
        when comboBox.Items.CurrentPosition < comboBox.Items.Count - 1 
             && comboBox.Items.MoveCurrentToNext():
      case Key.Up 
        when comboBox.Items.CurrentPosition > 0 
             && comboBox.Items.MoveCurrentToPrevious():
      {
        // Prevent the filter from re-apply as this would override the
        // current selection start index
        ComboBox.IsNavigationKeyPressed = true;

        // Ensure the Dispatcher en-queued delegate 
        // (and the invocation of the SelectCurrentItem() method)
        // executes AFTER the FilterOnTextInput() event handler.
        // This is because key input events have a higher priority
        // than text change events by default. The goal is to make the filtering 
        // triggered by the TextBox.TextChanged event ignore the changes 
        // introduced by this KeyDown event.
        // DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle will force to "override" this behavior.
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
          () =>
          {
            ComboBox.SelectCurrentItem(textBox, comboBox);
            ComboBox.IsNavigationKeyPressed = false;
          }, 
          DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        break;
      }
    }
  }

  private static void SelectCurrentItem(TextBox textBox, System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox)
  {
    comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBox.Items.CurrentItem;
    if (ComboBox.TextBoxSelectionStartMap.TryGetValue(textBox, out int selectionStart))
    {
      textBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
    }
  }

  private static void EnableAutocompleteFilterOnComboBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var comboBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
    ComboBox.EnableAutocompleteFilter(comboBox);
  }

  private static void EnableAutocompleteFilter(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox)
  {
    if (comboBox.TryFindVisualChildElement(out TextBox editTextBox))
    {
      ComboBox.TextBoxComboBoxMap.Add(editTextBox, comboBox);
      ComboBox.ComboBoxTextBoxMap.Add(comboBox, editTextBox);
      editTextBox.TextChanged += ComboBox.FilterOnTextInput;

      // Need to receive handled KeyDown event
      comboBox.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(HandleKeyDownWhileFiltering), true);
    }
  }

  private static void DisableAutocompleteFilter(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox comboBox)
  {
    if (comboBox.TryFindVisualChildElement(out TextBox editTextBox))
    {
      ComboBox.TextBoxComboBoxMap.Remove(editTextBox);
      editTextBox.TextChanged -= ComboBox.FilterOnTextInput;
    }
  }
}
```

**Extensions.cs**

```
public static class Extensions
{ 
  /// <summary>
  /// Traverses the visual tree towards the leafs until an element with a matching element type is found.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="TChild">The type the visual child must match.</typeparam>
  /// <param name="parent"></param>
  /// <param name="resultElement"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(this DependencyObject parent, out TChild resultElement)
    where TChild : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (parent is Popup popup)
    {
      parent = popup.Child;
      if (parent == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
    {
      DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);
      if (childElement is TChild child)
      {
        resultElement = child;
        return true;
      }

      if (childElement.TryFindVisualChildElement(out resultElement))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

**Usage Example**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          IsEditable="True"
          ComboBox.IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: Thank you. What is `TryFindVisualChildElement`?

Comment: A helper to traverse the visual tree. I have added it to complete the example

Comment: I'm confused. Is this a behavior or a Control? If control, why doesn't it inherit from built-in `ComboBox`?

Comment: It's basically an Attached Property. When setting it to enabled on any `ComboBox` it will track text changes of the edit `TextBlock` which is part of the `ComboBox` template. See the _Usage Example_.

Comment: If you prefer to extend `ComboBox` you can do it and use the exact same code, starting from calling `EnableAutocompleteFilter` from the `Loaded` event handler. This will achieve the same result.

Comment: ah I see. Actually the name of your class was confusing me. It should be called anything but `ComboBox`. OK, so I tried it and it works, except for one thing: selection through arrow keys no longer works. Means if you type a few letters while the dropdown is open, it filters correctly, but if you then want to quickly select one of the filtered items by pressing Down Arrow key, it doesn't work (unlike the default behavior of ComboBox).

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem I described?

Comment: Yes, I can. This seems to be a focus issue. The Key events are handled by the `ComboBox` directly while the `TextBox` has focus. I will try to find a fix later.

Comment: I just updated the answer. Since the filtering modifies the collection view used by the `ItemsControl` the internal keyboard navigation doesn't work as long as the filtered collection view is active. I added simple keyboard navigation up/down handling to compensate this behavior. The `Dispatcher` together with the `DispatcherPriority` is required to ensure a different event handler priority than the framework's default flow.

Comment: Brilliant stuff. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One control seems to work fine, but not when there is more than one on the same view. As I'm manipulating one ComboBox, the others start acting strangely, updating at random and so on. I'm guessing it has something to do with the static members?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would you mind to elaborate more on the scenario and the observed behavior so that I can review the code based on that information or try to reproduce the behavior? Maybe you could create a small example and post a pastebin link here? Do those misbehaving ComboBoxes bind to the same source collection?

Comment: They all bind to the same source collection but each CB has a different SelectedItem binding. When I'm typing into one CB I'll see the others randomly change - either the text/selected item disappears or a different item gets selected (unrelated to what I've just done in the CB I'm editing) . The CB appears within a ContentTemplate inside a Style. I've tried adding x:Shared="False" to the Style but it hasn't helped. I'll try and put together a standalone example - it might help me narrow down whether it's something to do with the code itself, or the way I'm using it in a style.

Comment: Another (possibly related?) issue. One of my views doesn't use the above style, just regular comboboxes with the attached prop applied. These appear within a tabbed UI, and as I switch tabs I get a "An item with the same key has already been added" exception (EnableAutocompleteFilter() method, TextBoxComboBoxMap.Add... line).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will find time later and check it. This is likely something trivial. I assume it's related to the collection view that is used by the ItemsControl. When you bind multiple  ItemsControls to the same collection they use the same default view. When filtering on one control will of course affect the others too. If this is the case, we can replace the default collection view so that each uses a different view. This would be a quick fix. I hope you can wait until later. A really small example might help, so that I don't have to waste time trying to reproduce it. Just hang on.

Comment: I've just tried converting your code to a custom ComboBox control, which has got rid of all the static fields/members, however the problem is still occurring, so I suspect it is related to how I'm using the ComboBoxes inside a style/control template after all. I'm still investigating.

Comment: So after all that, it *is* because every ComboBox ItemsSource is bound to the same observable collection. I don't understand what caused the problems though. The ItemsSource is just that - something to populate the CBs, so how can changing the SelectedItem in one CB affect another? (The ItemsSource bindings are even OneWay, the OC property has a private setter, and the collection contents never change).

Comment: @AndrewStephens I was trying to explain that when binding to a collection you never bind directly to the instance. Instead, the binding engine creates a default `ICollectionView` that wraps the underlying collection. The default collection view is always the same instance for every binding to the underlying collection. Now, when filtering one collection view e.g. for one `ComboBox` then this of course affects a second `ComboBox` that is bound to the same collection and therefore using the exact same default collection view.

Comment: @AndrewStephens However, unless you bind all ItemControls to the same SelectedItem property or you set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `true` or `null` (the default is `null`) the `SelectedItem` properties should be independent. You can try to explicitly set the `ComboBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem ` property to `false`. `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` controls whether the `SelectedItem` is also set on the collection view (`IColectionView.CurrentItem`). This would cause the collection view (all use the same default view) to synchronize the `SelectedItem` value.

Comment: @AndrewStephens See: [Microsoft learn: Collection views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-8.0#collection-views)

Comment: @AndrewStephens I guess the first issue is resolved and can be considered default behavior. Let me know if you want a different behavior and don't know how to prevent the ItemsControl from using the default collection view. You would have to bind each ComboBox to its own (non-default) collection view (of the same underlying collection). That's quite simple. Just create a dedicated instance of [`ListCollectionView `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.listcollectionview?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) and bind each to a different ComboBox.

Comment: @AndrewStephens I would be happy if you could render the case that throws the exception when you use this behavior in a TabControl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256961/discussion-between-andrew-stephens-and-bioniccode).