# ComboBox with filter feature - attachable property was not found in type 'ComboBox'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I currently have a small application thats written in MVVM architecture. I have the following folder structure. A folder for Commands, Models, ViewModels and finally a folder for my Views. I am trying to implement a Combobox in my DataGrid that has a drop down that filters the list based on the text I enter in that Combobox. I think I have found the solution posted in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008226/combobox-with-both-filter-and-auto-complete), However it doesnt work for me when I implement it. I hate to create another question for it but unfortunately I cannot comment on that post due to lack of reputation.

The way I implement the code is I created two classes ComboBox.cs and Extensions.cs (outside not in any namespace or folder) and copy pasted the code in the link above as is. I then went to the xaml of my already working DataGrid and added

> ComboBox.IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled="True"

as suggested by the solution in the link. Here is my xaml for a portion of the DataGrid:
`

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name" ComboBox.IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled="True"
                        Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.CombosAndLoadCasesList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>`
```

There was a comment by how the class name of ComboBox shouldnt be called ComboBox so I changed it to something else and I am still not able to make it work. This is error message I am getting:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   XLS0415 The attachable property 'IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled' was not found in type 'ComboBox'.   Combonito   ComboInfoUI.xaml    49

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   XDG0012 The member "IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled" is not recognized or is not accessible.  Combonito   ComboInfoUI.xaml    49

Comment: I think the syntax is: yourNameSpaceWhereYourExtensionLives:ClassName.IsFilterOnAutocompleteEnabled="True" And you have to define this namespace at the top of your XAML where all namespaces are defined.

Comment: Separate folder for commands is a bit strange. I would expect to see a command in it's owning viewmodel. Perhaps referencing injected services or wrapping something calls an an endpoint. Viewmodels are also often view specific so I would more usually have a folder for a logical grouping that contains it's view(s) and viewmodel(s).

Comment: @Andy Im still new to MVVM and this is what I saw in one of the tutorials online. I currently have 2 views and they use the same view model (my application doesnt call for 2 seperate viewmodels for my 2 seperate views). My commands class doesnt hold any information that is displayed so why would it be in its own viewmodel?

Comment: @Klamsi what if the ComboBox & Extension classes are not in any name space. Doesnt this mean they are accessible everywhere or do I have to set the datacontext?